# Can TCP handle a stream which never ends in a single connection?

Tags: tcp

This is more of a theoretical question. Let us say that there is an infinite data source, which keeps pushing data every second. Some device which monitors "Solar events", and sends events to a back-end system continuously, every nanosecond ( to mean its a continuous stream ). And the back-end system wants to transmit the live data to another remote system over TCP. Can TCP handle the infinite data stream in a single TCP connection ?

I'm aware of the sequence number limitation, but with TCP timestamps, the sequence numbers will properly wrap around, and it should not pose a problem. Also, assume that the system has several terabytes of memory ( which can be considered close to an infinite memory model ). If I just give the base address of where the stream starts, will TCP able to proceed ( segmenting, transmitting, re-transmitting .. etc ) continuously in a single TCP connection, without bothering on whether the data ever ends ?

My guess is that since TCP never expects any stream length parameter, it should be possible. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, yes.  As long as the data is byte, ('octet'), aligned, data on TCP streams can be piped anywhere, (see any router).  TCP comms is a byte stream - it doesn't care about message boundaries.  The windowed protocol has built-in flow-control, so it should all work.